# Moq + xunit + asp.net core: service return null value

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, moq, xunit

I use xUnit as test runner in my asp.net core application.
Here is my test theory:

```
[Theory(DisplayName = "Search advisors by advisorId"),
        ClassData(typeof(SearchAdvisorsByIdTestData))]
    public async void SearchAdvisors_ByAdvisorId(int brokerDealerId, FilterParams filter)
    {
        // Arrange
        var _repositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>();
        // Do this section means we bypass the repository layer
        _repositoryMock
             .Setup(x => x.SearchAdvisors(filter.CID.Value, new AdvisorSearchOptions
             {
                 SearchKey = filter.SeachKey,
                 AdvisorId = filter.AdvisorId,
                 BranchId = filter.BranchId,
                 City = filter.City,
                 Skip = filter.Skip,
                 Limit = filter.Limit,
                 RadiusInMiles = filter.Limit,
                 Longitude = filter.Longitude,
                 Latitude = filter.Latitude
             }))
             .Returns(Task.FromResult<SearchResults<Advisor>>(
                new SearchResults<Advisor>()
                {
                    Count = 1,
                    Limit = 0,
                    Skip = 0,
                    ResultItems = new List<SearchResultItem<Advisor>>() {
                        //some initialize here
                    }
                })
            );

        _advisorService = new AdvisorService(_repositoryMock.Object, _brokerDealerRepositoryMock, _brokerDealerServiceMock);

        // Action
        var model = await _advisorService.Search(brokerDealerId, filter);

        Assert.True(model.AdvisorResults.Count == 1);
        Assert.True(model.AdvisorResults[0].LocationResults.Count > 0);
    }
```

The service like this

```
public async Task<ViewModelBase> Search(int brokerDealerId, FilterParams filter)
    {
        var opts = new AdvisorSearchOptions
        {
            SearchKey = filter.SeachKey,
            AdvisorId = filter.AdvisorId,
            BranchId = filter.BranchId,
            City = filter.City,
            Skip = filter.Skip,
            Limit = filter.Limit,
            RadiusInMiles = filter.Limit,
            Longitude = filter.Longitude,
            Latitude = filter.Latitude
        };

        var searchResults = await _repository.SearchAdvisors(filter.CID.Value, opts);  // line 64 here

        if (searchResults.Count == 0 && Utils.IsZipCode(filter.SeachKey))
        {


        }

        //Some other code here

        return model;
    }
```

The issue was after run line 64 in the service. I always get null value of searchResults although I already mocked _repository in the test.

What was my wrong there?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument matcher for `SearchAdvisors()` mock does not work because you pass different instances of `AdvisorSearchOptions`. First instance is created in `_repositoryMock.Setup()` statement and the second one is created in `Search()` method itself.

There are several ways to fix this problem:

1.If you don't care about verifying whether instance `of AdvisorSearchOptions` passed to repository is filled correctly, just use `It.IsAny<AdvisorSearchOptions>()` matcher in mock setup:

```
_repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.SearchAdvisors(filter.CID.Value, It.IsAny<AdvisorSearchOptions>()))
    .Returns(/*...*/);
```

2.In previous case the test will not verify that `AdvisorSearchOptions` is filled correctly. To do this, you could override `Object.Equals()` method in `AdvisorSearchOptions` class so that mock call will match for different instances:

```
public class AdvisorSearchOptions
{
    // ...

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var cmp = obj as AdvisorSearchOptions;
        if (cmp == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return SearchKey == cmp.SearchKey && AdvisorId == cmp.AdvisorId &&
            /* ... compare all other fields here */
    }
}
```

3.Another way to verify object passed to mock is to save the instance via Mock callback and then compare required fields:

```
AdvisorSearchOptions passedSearchOptions = null;
_repositoryMock
     .Setup(x => x.SearchAdvisors(filter.CID.Value, It.IsAny<AdvisorSearchOptions>()))
     .Returns(Task.FromResult<SearchResults<Advisor>>(
        new SearchResults<Advisor>()
        {
            Count = 1,
            Limit = 0,
            Skip = 0,
            ResultItems = new List<SearchResultItem<Advisor>>() {
                //some initialize here
            }
        })
    )
    .Callback<int, AdvisorSearchOptions>((id, opt) => passedSearchOptions = opt);

//  Action
//  ...

Assert.IsNotNull(passedSearchOptions);
Assert.AreEqual(filter.SearchKey, passedSearchOptions.SearchKey);
Assert.AreEqual(filter.AdvisorId, passedSearchOptions.AdvisorId);
// Check all other fields here
// ...
```

Comment: Thank for your explanation carefully. In this test case I want the AdvisorId in AdvisorSearchOptions must have a certain value (not zero). That why I explicit declare AdvisorSearchOptions.

Comment: 3rd options from my answer is the best choice to assert that correct `AdvisorId` was used in `AdvisorSearchOptions`: `Assert.AreNotEqual(0, passedSearchOptions.AdvisorId);`

Comment: Where is change passedSearchOptions value?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that line in code snippet. Check updated answer. `passedSearchOptions` is assigned in `Callback` lambda.